# Orthogonal kernel and image of matrix implies this decomposition with unitary matrix?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $\operatorname{Ker}(A)\perp \operatorname{Im}(A)$. I read in a solution that in this case there exists a unitary matrix $U$ such that $$A=U\left[\begin{array}{ c | c }
    M & 0 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]U^{-1}$$ where $M$ is an $r\times r$ invertible matrix with $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$, but I don't really understand why this is the case.

I know the classical result that there exist invertible matrices $P, Q\in M_n(\mathbb{C})$ such that $$A=P\left[\begin{array}{ c | c }
    I_r & 0 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]Q$$ where $I_r$ denotes the $r\times r$ unit matrix and again $r=\operatorname{rank}(A)$, but I don't know how to use that orthogonality condition to deduce the existence of that unitary matrix $U$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\text{Ker } A \perp \text{Im } A$, there is an orthonormal basis $\{u_n\}$ whose first $r$ elements form a basis of $\text{Im } A$ and last $n-r$ elements form a basis of $\text{Ker } A$.  Since these are orthonormal, the matrix $U$ whose columns are $u_1, \ldots, u_n$ is unitary.

The last $r-n$ columns of $U^{-1}AU$ are $0$, because these are $U^{-1} A u_k$, $k = r+1\ldots n$, where $u_k \in \text{Ker } A$.
Moreover the last $r-n$ rows of $U^{-1} A U$ are $0$, because these are $u_k^* A U$ for $k  = r+1 \ldots n$, and these $u_k$ are orthogonal to $\text{Im } A$ and thus to the columns of $A U$.
Thus $U^{-1} A U$ is of the form $\left[\begin{array}{ c | c }
    M & 0 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0
  \end{array}\right]$, where $M$ has rank $r$ because that is the rank of $A$ and thus of $U^{-1} A U$.  And this says
$$ A = U \left[\begin{array}{ c | c }
    M & 0 \\
    \hline
    0 & 0
  \end{array}\right] U^{-1}$$

Comment: thank you! I know that this might be dumb, but why do we know that such an orthonormal basis $\{u_n\}$ exists? Is it because $\mathbb{C}^n=\operatorname{Ker}(A)\oplus \operatorname {Im}(A)$ and the orthonormality follows from the perpendicularity condition?

Comment: The first $r$ elements are an orthonormal basis of $\text{Im } A$ and the last $n-r$ are an orthonormal basis of $\text{Ker } A$.  The fact that $\text{Ker } A \perp \text{Im A}$ tells you that the first $r$ elements are orthogonal to the last $n-r$.

Comment: oh right, thank you so much for your help!